# How to add dynamic channel name to connect with other user using Agora video call for 1 to 1 and 1 to mant calls using flutter

Tags: flutter, video, voice, agora.io

I have gone through agora flutter quickstart sample app but there we are giving channel name which should be same on both sides. Now for a dynamic number how do we generate dynamic channel name which will be same for sender and receiver . As i am new to Agora am not able to link the dynamic channel name.

The code is same as Agora quickstart sample app.Also I am having the APP ID and temp token generated But not able to understand where do we use the temp token.Your help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you please let me know how you get the temp token. did you get it without enabling app certificate or you are generating token from your own server?

Comment: No I have enabled app certificate and after that only temp token is generated

Answer (score 2):

For joining a channel, you have to pass the following parameters:

```
joinChannel(String token, String channelId, String info, int uid)
```

Where token, info, and uid are optional fields. While channel name is a required field. So you can pass the joinChannel function like:

```
joinChannel(null, 'channelName', null, 0)
```

You can either take an input for the channel name and use it to join a channel or you can simply pass the channel name inside the function as shown above.

To generate a token go to this link: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/token_server_python?platform=Python

This will help you generate a token from your server. There are multiple options available for the language you want to develop in, use that to generate your token.

You can get more information about the passed attributes and other functions over [here](https://github.com/Meherdeep/agora-flutter-documentation#joinchannel)

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i want to know how will the receiver will know that to join to same channel as the sender which will be dynamic in nature and cannot be entered manully according to mobile number (Just like whatsapp video call or voice call)

Comment: You can provide your own channel name. So lets say that you built an app with a certain app id. Now if you wanted to talk to that person x you can simply add his phone number as the channel name or his name or any random text.  Now for that person x he will have to mention his own phone number, name or whatever you decide your channel name to be.
This channel name need to be shared between the user and receiver before hand.

Comment: So you are saying the that person X needs to enter manually from his phone and then only we can go forward right??

Comment: 2021 agora settings just changed. How do i create a dynamic channel name with my app with dnamic token.

Comment: @mananvora No, you can have that from your backend as well.

Comment: @b.john To create dynamic channel have a look at this: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/real-time-messaging-and-video-with-dynamic-channels-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/